# CSS in CKEDITOR - How to make a HTML code like <p><!-- pagebreak --></p> display in red color?

Tags: css, ckeditor, wysiwyg

We used tinymce in our application and trying to migrate to CKEDITOR .
All the contents are stored in the database with `<p><!-- pagebreak --></p>` to do pagebreaking while generating pdf contents.

Now we are trying to migrate to CKEDITOR , the HTML code works fine and pdf generation also works fine . But the problem is that CKEDITOR doesnt display anything display for 
`<p><!-- pagebreak --></p>` - It is like blank in WSIWYG editor .

I need to create a solution wherein CKEDITOR `<p><!-- pagebreak --></p>` with a CSS display ... like say a RED LINE . 
I cant modify the code as it is stored in the DB , hence I need CKEDITOR to do some CSS tricks to display `<p><!-- pagebreak --></p>` as a red line in its editor

Comment: Thanks Henesnarfel for editing . From my understanding , CKEDITOR reneders the HTML content into a DIV and hence if I can hack the code code during this parsing to replace with a css / style display then I would achieve my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is what I would do if you truly want to migrate and not have to hack any code would be to convert all the `<p><!-- pagebreak --></p>` in your database entries to `<div class="page-break"></div>` and set the css value of

```
.page-break
{
    page-break-after:always`
}
```

Or to use what CKEDITOR does

```
<div style="page-break-after: always;">
    <span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a difficult thing for us , we will have to migrate DB for many clients . It is basically a UI issue for us - just to get a display .

Comment: @Nishant Then you have a few other options. 1. to hack the code to make it convert from the TINYMCE version to the CKEDITOR version.  2. When you pull the items from the database to do whatever you do a conversion there.

Comment: 2) is a good proposal , would be considering that . Didn't get the point no:1 - what is that ? I need a styling solution basically from CKEDITOR .

Comment: I misunderstood I guess what you meant by hack.  I assumed you were trying to actually hack CKEDITOR not the code from the database

Comment: I dont want to touch the database for this as it would be messy .In my opinion the best way would be the interact with CKEDITOR while parsing HTML to make a DIV and then replace all the comments with pagebreak to a image tag .

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot style that HTML tag without affecting other content in that field.

You see it is defined as simply a paragraph tag with no class or other defining attributes at all (`<p>` as opposed to `<p class="line-break">`). That makes it impossible for you to "hook" your custom style into just those nodes with CSS.

The tag content is simply an HTML comment, which is never displayed and therefore cannot be styled.

You *could* style this if you are pulling the CK-encoded text from a database using a language like PHP for display, in which case you could do a `str_replace` for the HTML you noted and virtually injecting a hook such as a class name.

One other option is to use JavaScript to search the HTML for that node and dynamically inject either a class name or another node such as a horizontal rule (`<hr>`).

Once you have a class on just those paragraphs, the CSS you'd use would be something like:

`p.line-break { border-bottom: 2px solid red; }`